# Почему "Android ic_launcher@" то прозрачный, то нет?

Tags: java, android, design, icon

Вот `ic_launcher` на `Android 4.2.2`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот тот же самый `ic_launcher` на `Android 4.4.2`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему на некоторых версиях Android вокруг `ic_launcher` появляется зелёная кайма и как её убрать?

Comment: это особенность лончера. На "чистом", AOSP лончере иконки выглядят нормально. На некоторых кастомных лончерах иконки выглядят по разному. На втором скриншоте видно же, что зелёнка не только на иконке вашего приложения.

Comment: лончер иконки скругляет, но если остаются прозрачные места, то он их закрашивает. Что делать? Ничего. Смиритесь, такие лончеры исчезнут, да будет Material Design!

Comment: Большое Спасибо за ответы! Придётся смириться.

Answer (score 1):

это из-за настроек темы самого телефона. не в приложении и ИДЕ дело, только в настройках темы и стиля Иконок.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]